# insert a column from another df into another df as a column. stucked for hours! merge(join) with different column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

these 2 df i have tried different code from join (which it requires a common column), to union and some other code to merge, tho i can't get the result i want, i tried also straight forward

```
data.join(tdf, how='inner').select('*')
data.join(tdf, how='outer').select('*')
```

none of the 2 above codes gave me a wanted df.

data.show()

```
|_c0|         description|   medical_specialty|        sample_name|       transcription|            keywords|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|Laparoscopic Gas...|PAST MEDICAL HIST...|bariatrics, lapar...|
|  2| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|Laparoscopic Gas...|"HISTORY OF PRESE...| at his highest h...|
|  3| 2-D M-Mode. Dopp...| Cardiovascular /...|2-D Echocardiogr...|2-D M-MODE: , ,1....|cardiovascular / ...|
|  4|  2-D Echocardiogram| Cardiovascular /...|2-D Echocardiogr...|1.  The left vent...|cardiovascular / ...|
```

How to add the age column as a column of the above df/ Or how to merge these dfs

tdf.show()

```
|age|
+---+
|   |
| 42|
|   |
|   |
| 30|
|   |
|   |
```

goal:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+---+
|_c0|         description|   medical_specialty|        sample_name|      transcription|             keywords|age|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|  1| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|Laparoscopic Gas...|PAST MEDICAL HIST...|bariatrics, lapar...|   |
|  2| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|Laparoscopic Gas...|"HISTORY OF PRESE...| at his highest h...| 42|
|  3| 2-D M-Mode. Dopp...| Cardiovascular /...|2-D Echocardiogr...|2-D M-MODE: , ,1....|cardiovascular / ...|   |
|  4|  2-D Echocardiogram| Cardiovascular /...|2-D Echocardiogr...|1.  The left vent...|cardiovascular / ...|   |
```

Comment: you need to `join` on a `key` that is present in both dfs

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, so Mohammad, i have to add another column with the same specs of a column that is in the datadf, right?

Comment: if u have a `_c0` corresponding to `age` in `tdf ` then yes u could join them and that unique key should have already been there. you cant add that unless u know when the age will be a certain value based on `_c0`.

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi how can i add the column same like **_c0** to agedf. `agedf.withColumn('_c0', range(1,4999)`, didn't work ,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to join the two dataframes based on their row_number as your data contains the row_number but your age df doesn't.
So you can add a row number then join your dataframe like:

```
tdf = tdf.withColumn('Row_id',f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(f.lit('a'))))
joined_data = data.join(tdf, data._c0==tdf.Row_id).select('*')
```

This will join the age column to your existing dataframe.